# Multiplication by integrable function can't change convergence to zero

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $f_n$ be a uniformly bounded sequence of non-negative measurable functions whose integrals converge to zero and let $g$ be a non-negative integrable function. How can one show that the integrals of $gf_n$ also converge to zero?

I'm not sure where to start but I feel that what I want to reach is something like
$$ \int gf_n \leq \int g \int f_n \rightarrow 0$$
but I can't see how to get there. I think somehow we must also use Bounded Convergence, but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int f_n g=\int_{g>N} f_ng+\int_{g\leq N} f_ng$. Uniform boundedness of $(f_n)$ and integrability of $g$  shows that the first term can be made less than $\epsilon$ by choosing $N$ large enough (independently of $n$). For fixed $N$ the second term tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ since this term is bounded by $N\int f_n$.

[$\int_{g>N} g \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$ by DCT].